# What's the difference between windowBackground and background for activities style?

Tags: android, background, styles, android-activity, android-theme

I have a background set for all of the activities of the app by using the "android:background" parameter in the styles and setting the theme of the application to link to this style.

All worked well, till I've noticed that for a dialog with a list of items, it makes each item to have the full size of the background .

After changing the parameter being used to "android:windowBackground" it seems to work fine in this case too.

Why does it occur? What is the difference between the two?

Also , does setting "android:windowBackground" to @null as [written here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html) provide the same speed boost as using "android:background"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`android:background` is the background color (drawable to be precise) of a view component whereas `android:windowBackground` is the background color of the window (activity or dialog) in which your view resides.

By default views are transparent (i.e. no background color) so visually it looks like they are taking the color from the underlying window.

Notice how the article you linked to mentions setting the `windowBackground` to null and not the background for fullscreen views. This is a common technique to avoid overdraws.

But the same principle can be applied to views if you have one view completely hide the other view.

Example: [gist.github.com/floatingmonkey/5474959](http://gist.github.com/floatingmonkey/5474959)

Comment: So why does the activity/application have the android:background, if it actually sets it for each of its views? i don't understand its purpose .btw you can also set an image as a background and not just a color. Also, fixed the confusion of the article.

Comment: you can pass any valid android:whatever attribute to any component. it will just ignore the attribute if it doesn't apply for that component. (this can be confusing but its how android ensures backward compatibility). also yes you can pass images, color or any drawable for that matter (gradient, shape even animation) as a value for background and windowBackground.

Comment: but i still don't get how come using an image on android:background on an activity/application makes everything use it, instead of just the background of the activity, and why it even exists there if it has such a weird behavior. you can try this test too : create a new hello world app, and set the theme that was created for you to use this attribute with an image. you will notice that many views on the activity will now use this background.

Comment: when you apply styles as a theme on the activity it also applies to the all the view within that activity. again some properties might make sense only at the window level and vice versa - all the properties that don't apply to a component will be ignored. this can be confusing and lead to errors but it also is very flexible.

Comment: interesting. you mean that it's just an example of using styles across the entire app, for example, this way i can set a style of all textView instances  if i want to? is this the purpose of the attribute?

Comment: yup. just set it as a theme attribute on a window (activity or dialog) and it will apply to all textviews in your view hierarchy in that window.

Comment: Cool. can you please give an example of how to use it (for any type of view that you choose, like textview for example) ? i will tick your answer soon after.