# Changing the background color affects children

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to change the basic background color in my app by adding a single line to the main application theme:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

However it's cascading down to child objects like the actionbar and logo like this:

[image: Weird color cascading]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:windowBackground` instead of `background` attribute:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. Can you shed any light on why my original code cascades like that? Is there a way to inherit the background color of the parent even if it isn't explicitly named?

Comment: Not sure but I think your behaviour `background` gives a background color for all the views whereas `windowBackground` is only for the background window, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239788/2668136