# Setting backgroundcolor in theme gives graphical buggy dialog

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, themes

In my activity theme in the `themes.xml` I have set a background color in order to move away from the default (transparent/white?) background color to my own.

```
<item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
```

Unfortunately, when the I am showing my loading dialog the color shines halfway through that dialog now. Was this to be expected?

[image: Dialog with buggy red/transparent color]

I have tried to use different themes, also defined by own dialog theme subclassing from Holo Light setting the background color explicitly to white, but the problem persists, only the currently still white areas are changed in this case.

What can I do? The only alternative is currently to use the Tradiotional Dialog Theme.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Which views should have red color and which shouldn't?

Comment: @vokilam The theme background color addresses the background color of the activity. Without it we have the default color (transparent/white).

Comment: Try to set `android:windowBackground` instead

Comment: @vokilam That did it! Thanks so much. Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `android:windowBackground` instead. `android:background` attribute is applied to all nested views. Here is the discussion: [What's the difference between windowBackground and background for activities style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425868/whats-the-difference-between-windowbackground-and-background-for-activities-sty)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's some padding or margins to the left and right of the title. If you're using the built-in `ProgressDialog` I'd suggest creating your own `Dialog` instead, that way you can change anything you want about it. Just create your own xml layout and create the dialog like this:

```
protected static Dialog getProgressDialog(Activity activity) {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View progressDialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog, null);

    dialog.setContentView(progressDialogView);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    return dialog;
}
```