# android:windowBackground not working

Tags: android, android-styles, android-dialog

I have created a custom dialog theme like so:

```
<style name="dialogLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">attr/theme_dialogBackground</item>
</style>
```

However when I then run the app, the `dialog` background is its default (transparent on one device and black on another).

However if I change `android:windowBackground` to `android:background`, the correct behaviour for `android:background` is seen, and the default background of all the views in the dialog becomes the specified value, as it should.

Changing the value of android:windowBackground to an @drawable or an @color work as they should.

I know what the difference between `android:windowBackground` and `android:background` is, and using `android:background` is not what I need, as I only want the window background colour to change.

So why is `android:windowBackground` not being applied?

Comment: Where is this theme used?

Comment: In my base theme I declare

<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/dialogLight</item>

Comment: You want the background of dialog to change. then why do you require windoebackground? Quoting docs " For instance, windowNoTitle and windowBackground are style properties that are effective only when the style is applied as a theme to an Activity or application. "

Comment: How else would you change the background of the dialog?

Comment: using background  attribute which was working as mentioned in your post

Comment: But android:background doesn't change the dialog background, it changes the default background of all sub-views in the dialog, which is not what I want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425868/whats-the-difference-between-windowbackground-and-background-for-activities-sty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124069/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-luke).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As @Raghunandan explained, android:windowBackground needs to reference a drawable, not a colour as I was doing