# Android splashscreen background instead of windowBackground

Tags: android, android-styles

My splashscreen was below the navigationbar when using `windowBackground`.  I was wondering if I can use the `background` property instead of `windowBackground`? I have tried it on my emulator and it works fine. But because all the tutorials talk about `windowBackground` I was wondering if there are some caveats?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here, maybe this answers your question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425868/whats-the-difference-between-windowbackground-and-background-for-activities-sty

Comment: @Grisgram That explains the difference. But I'm still not sure if it can be used on the splashscreen. Since the splashscreen is shown before the activity is loaded. But apparently the background can be set already through styles.xml. I'm just worried it might not work on some older Android versions or specific phones. But couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Just for a splash (i.e. something that is only on a single activity at startup, if I understand you right) IMHO you are fine using background.
Not sure about the drawing order (maybe the OS draws window background before inflating the entire layout, which could lead to the effect, that your splash becomes visible later...delayed... compared to windowBackground)

Comment: @Grisgram That's what I'm worried about. The SplashScreen is only visible at startup and in the `onCreate` I'm immediately starting another activity and finishing this one. So the SplashScreen is only visible during the app loading (so before calling onCreate). I've tested it using the emulator and my phone and it works there. But I don't know if it works everywhere. So I wanted to know if somebody knows the caveats of using this property or if there are none.